# CSS - Swap color items

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is:

Assume that I have the following list:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

I want to alternate between two colours so for example:

- Item 1 (Blue)
- Item 2 (Orange)
- Item 3 (Blue)
- Item 4 (Orange)

But I want this behaviour to be controlled in CSS so I can just write:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS :nth-child

```
li { color: blue; }
li:nth-child(odd) { color: orange; }
```

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/6yj1j6dk/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo class:

```css
ul li:nth-child(2n+1) { color: blue; }
ul li:nth-child(2n) { color: orange; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```